# Изменение файлов в tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, развертывание

В `ubuntu` установил `tomcat` командой `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`
Файл `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html` - read only. Как можно изменить файлы в `webapps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно редактировать с правами суперпользователя, например:

```
sudo nano '/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html'
```

Comment: а поконкретней если можно? sudo chmod a+rw index.html не помогает

Comment: сама папка находится во владении пользователя root, чтобы редактировать там файлы, вам нужно запускать редактор с этим файлом от имени суперпользователя

Comment: благодарю! sudo idea '/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html' позволила изменить =)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat7/
sudo chmod -R 777 webapps
```